# How can add UNIQUE column to a table in a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, database, unique

I need `UNIQUE` column in my table.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
      id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
      name text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      blabla text NOT NULL
);
```

and I get an error:

> Column 'name' in table 'my_table' is of a type  that is invalid for
>   use as a key column in an index. Could not create constraint or index.
>   See previous errors.

So, How can add `UNIQUE` column in table?

Comment: your error says it all, you cannot add a unique constraint on a LOB field like `text`. i think you want `VARCHAR` / `CHAR`

Comment: Do you really need the `name` field to be of type `TEXT`? Are you sure you want to store gigabytes of data in there?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Use `varchar(n)` (where `n` is the max length needed) instead of the deprecated `text` data type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using VARCHAR / NVARCHAR instead of TEXT, because TEXT data type is deprecated - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
      id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
      name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT UQ_my_table_name UNIQUE,
      blabla VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

Also, consider naming your constraints rather than let a default name for it.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem lies with the data type you have specified for column name. Essentially 'text' is a large object (LOB) data type. SQL does not allow the creation of index over this particular data type. Other examples of such a data type would be varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), xml, and image.

I believe it is largely because these are not allocated any specific data size from the beginning and hence any index created would have to be changed if it's maximum limit is surpassed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx